# Asp.net Core localizer without automatic code from Resource Managers

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core

According to asp.net core documentation [asp.net core localization documents](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html) localization needs to be done like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

namespace Localization.StarterWeb.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AboutController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<AboutController> _localizer;

        public AboutController(IStringLocalizer<AboutController> localizer)
        {
            _localizer = localizer;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return _localizer["About Title"];
        }
   }
}
```

These things have to be accomplished:

- IStringLocalizer has to be used with the type of the class specified as generic
- localizer instance has to be called with a string information

Two thoughts:

1. Why is it necessary to have the type of the class defined for that interface? Looks like an IoC necessity to me.
2. Method _localizer["default text"] is some kind of sub optimal because

   a) I do want to have people who are professionals localizing texts doing also the defaults. I don't want to have default as magic strings flying around

   b) In case that a string couldn't be found I would like to be informed about it. In this way I can only obtain it when the language is different from default

   c) Why do we loose the straight procedure with ResourceManager's automatic generated code?

I guess I miss anything?

P.S.: I discussed this item also [Where are the autogen properties in asp.net core localizers?](http://codingsoul.de/2016/09/26/where-are-the-autogen-properties-in-asp-net-core-localizers/).

Comment: I'm not sure "I don't like this API, why was it designed this way?" questions are suitable for SO.